# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 + MongoDB, Add custom hydrator to pagination

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

Im working in a zend framework 2 project.

In the fetchAll of my listener I have:

```
    $artifacts = $this->documentManager->createQueryBuilder('App\Document\Artifact')
        ->hydrate(true)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    $paginatorOrm = new DoctrinePaginator($artifacts);
    $paginatorZend = new Paginator($paginatorOrm);
    return $paginatorZend;
```

This code is working fine, I can see a paginated collection of all the artifacts. The problem is:

- If hydrate(true): Doctrine ORM generates an AppDocumentArtifactHydrator.php file to hydrate the object, and I see in output a paginated collection with all the information of all the artifacts.
- If hydrate(false): Then I see a JSON structure with all the fields of the artifact.

How can I add my own Hydrator to the $artifactsCollection? (In the collection, for each artifact, I want to give only the name, ID, and link to itself).

Months ago I worked in a similar project, using ZF2 + Doctrine 2 + MySQL, and I could create in the onBootstrap

```
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('MyHydrator', 'MyApp\Hydrators\MyEntity');
```

And all worked fine. Now I'm trying to do the same, but instead of $entityManager I have [$documentManager](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.DocumentManager.html), and I don't see this option.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution? I haven't found any solution in google...